# data comparision between two different database fails in ssdt visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I tried to compare two different databases objects/schema in ssdt visual studio 2013. Both the databases have similar tables. while comparing all the tables are not detected. what might be the reason ? can some one help me on this ?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely a lack of primary keys (maybe unique keys/constraints). If you need more flexibility, Red-Gate's SQL Compare has more options to define columns to use in the case that there aren't any defined unique constraints.